# Rails set a cookie from a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to set a cookie when I click on a `link_to` and I'm trying to achieve this with the following code:

```
<%= link_to "Choose Plan", new_user_registration_path(cookies.encrypted[:plan_id] = "12309") %>
```

The cookie is being created but it shows at the browser url and it messes up the redirect I have.

I also tried a `form_tag` and the plan_id doesn't appear on the url but it still messes up the redirect for some reason.

Any ideas on how to create cookie on `link_to`???

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas on how to create cookie on `link_to`?

A link is just a link. You click it, browser navigates to specified location. That's it. If you want to set the encrypted cookie when the link is clicked, you need to do it on the server (whereever that link points to).

You can intercept a click event on that link and set cookie with javascript. But that produce a normal cookie, not an encrypted one.

Answer (score 2):

```
new_user_registration_path(cookies.encrypted[:plan_id] = "12309")
```

You are passing your cookie as a parameter to new_user_registration_path. So of course it shows up in the URL.

What you need to do is go into the **new_user_registration** action in the respective controller and create the cookie there!

Based on the name I'm guessing the controller file is called **user_registrations_controller.rb** and the action is defined as **new**.

if you are using devise, you will need to go and edit devise's controller(and put your cookie there).